# Вычисление среднего арифметического

Tags: html, javascript

Есть исходный код: http://jsfiddle.net/vjjq554x/

Как сделать, чтобы из этих чисел вычиталось среднее арифметическое и записывалось в колонку "Средний балл"? Нужно так, чтобы не было никаких кнопок, при нажатии на которую вычислялся средний бал, а так, чтобы при открытии страницы средний балл уже был подсчитан.

**Обновление**

Я разрабатываю свой электронный журнал. Если у меня что-то не получается, то я ищу ответ в книге, в Интернете или, в конце концов, здесь, на форуме, где мне всегда помогают. В данном вопросе я спросил, как из данных оценок вычислить средний балл. У меня не получилось это сделать, потому что у переменной SPAN нет такого значения VALUE, как у переменной INPUT, и программа не видит цифры, из которых нужно высчитать среднее арифметическое. Я задал данный вопрос на примере оценок, потому что так будет понятней.

Я могу по-другому задать вопрос:

Есть код:

```
<span class=""><span>&nbsp;</span>4<span>&nbsp;</span></span><span class=""><span>&nbsp;</span>3<span>&nbsp;</span></span>
```

Нужно, чтобы в колонке "Средний балл" всё посчиталось через Javascript. В данном случае стоят оценки 3, 4. Следовательно, средний балл = 3,50. Как это сделать?..

Comment: @Никита___, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Я разрабатываю свой электронный журнал. Если у меня что-то не получается, то я ищу ответ в книге, в интернете, или в конце концов здесь, на форуме, где мне всегда помогают. В данном вопросе я спросил как из данных оценок вычислить средний балл. У меня не получилось это сделать, потому что у переменной SPAN нет такого значения VALUE, как у переменной INPUT, и программа не видит цифры, из которых нужно высчитать среднее арифметическое. Я задал данный вопрос на примере оценок, потому что так будет понятней.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое: уберите `<span>`, с помощью которых делаете отступы, они только мешают, а отступы можно сделать с помощью `padding и margin`.

Второе: в td с оценками по предмету у вас останется точное количество `<span>` со значениями. Добавьте уникальный id для каждой ячейки с оценками, например, - mark-0, mark-1... mark-n

Для одной строки:

```
td = document.getElementById('mark-0');
span = td.getElementsByTagName('span');
t = 0;
for (i=0;i<span.length;i++){
t += parseInt(span[i].innerText,10);
}
mid = t/(span.length+1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fzrb0peg/

Comment: Средний балл не подсчитывается. Кстати, пробелы действительно лишние оказались. http://jsfiddle.net/fzrb0peg/2/
__________
Кнопку я сделал временно.

Comment: Без кнопки:
http://jsfiddle.net/fzrb0peg/4/

1. Лишняя закрывающая кнопка.
2. Код выполняется в обработчике onLoad. Функцию в таком случае он не понимает.

3. +1 в делителе вычисления среденго - лишнее. Мой косяк.

Comment: можно обернуть в 
`for (j=0;j<2;j++){ //j<2 - по количеству строк в таблице

//document.getElementById('mark-0'); заменить на 'mark-'+j
....
// и тоже самое для res

}`

Answer (score 1):

Можешь вычислять средний бал при помощи javascript, но тогда будет небольшая задержка вычисления, т.е. пользователь открывает страницы и в колонке "Средний бал" видит пустоту. И после 0,001-1 секунд данная колонка заполнится. Возможно, вы даже этого и не заметите. :)

А по-хорошему заранее вычислять средний балл, но тогда надо задействовать php. Но, судя по вашему коду, там чистый HTML. И о php вы, наверное, не знаете. Поэтому JS вам в руки. :)

**UPD**

Генерируй id.

Например, у тебя есть N кол-во предметов и P кол-во оценок в каждом предмете. 
Если по-простому, то генерируешь:

```
<td id="N">(тут будет средний балл)</td>
<span id="N_P">(тут будет оценка)</span>
```

И в итоге у тебя получится что-то вроде:

```
<td id="1"></td> //Первый предмет
<span id="1_1"></span>
<span id="1_2"></span>
<span id="1_.."></span>
<span id="1_P"></span>
<td id="2"></td> //Второй предмет
<span id="2_1"></span>
<span id="2_2"></span>
<span id="2_.."></span>
<span id="2_P"></span>
<td id="N"></td> //И так далее
```

Имея ID, ты можешь легко на JS посчитать средний балл.

**UPD 2**

**Вот готовый код:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var i = 1; //Если нумерация предметов начинается с 1
        while ($('#' + i) != undefined) {
            var j = 1; //Если нумерация оценок начинается с 1
            var srednee = 0;
            while ($('#' + i + '_' + j) != undefined) {
                srednee = srednee + parseFloat($('#' + i + '_' + j).text());    
                j++;
            }
            $('#' + i).text(srednee);
            i++;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Я конечно, знаю, что это делается через Javascript. Но у меня вопрос - как? Я вроде пытался через Javascript, но почему-то ничего не вышло. Возможно, я допустил ошибки.

Comment: Смотри UPD моего ответа.

Comment: А вычисление среднего балла через Javascript как сделать? Можете написать код?
_____

 
    <script type="text/Javascript">
    var srball = document.getElementById('1_1')+document.getElementById('1_2')\2
    ...
    </script>

Верно?

Comment: Написал универсальный код, для всех предметов! Смотри UPD 2.

Получилось?

Comment: Спасибос Вам!

Comment: Рад помочь :)